# Firebase/Angular2: How to increment a record in Firebase with AngularFire2?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I want to increment a record in firebase using AngularFire2, below is my method:

```
     const productsQuery = this.af.database.list('/products/'+productKey,{ preserveSnapshot: true });
     const productUpdate = this.af.database.list('/products');
     productsQuery.subscribe(snapshots => {
            snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
            if (snapshot.key == "quantity") {
                productUpdate.update(productKey,{quantity: snapshot.val()+1});
            }
            });          
     });
```

But instead of incrimenting quantity just one time, this produces an infinite loop and the "quantity" record becomes too big,

any help guys?

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are subscribed on every value change and that is the reason why you are getting in the infinite loop. Try adding take(1) to the subscribe method.

```
const productsQuery = this.af.database.list('/products/'+productKey,{ preserveSnapshot: true });
 const productUpdate = this.af.database.list('/products');
 productsQuery.subscribe(snapshots => {
        snapshots.forEach(snapshot => {
        if (snapshot.key == "quantity") {
            productUpdate.update(productKey,{quantity: snapshot.val()+1});
        }
        });          
 }).take(1);
```

In this case, it should take the value only once.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it returns an error: Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Subscription'

Comment: Try importing  > import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'

Comment: Hi Igor, this works now but with two small changes, first of all use .take(1) or .first() (same meaning) in this.af.database.list('/products/'+productKey,{ preserveSnapshot: true }).take(1) (or .first) not at the end. second change is before using the above code we have to upgrade angularFire2 with  npm i angularfire2@next --save . thank you  for your help, I will accept your answer.